# Entity Framework report builder

Tags: entity-framework, reportbuilder

I am trying to implement a report builder similar to [this](http://devtools.korzh.com/easyquery/asp-net/). I want to be able to pass it a Entity framework DBContext and it should build a similar dashboard.

I am able to get all the models in the DBContext, but now i need to actually build a query to return the data based on the values the user has selected.

What is the best way to generate the sql ? Is there a way i can use Entity framework to get it to generate the sql for me ? Or should i write my own query parser, if this is the case is there good query parsers online that i can use ?

regards

Comment: Hi, I am in a similar situation. What did you do finally?

Comment: I never took that project further. Had other stuff to do.

Comment: ahh... @Captain0, anyways thanks for replying. :)